# Как разархивировать отдельный файл из zip архива в Android'e?

Tags: android, android-studio, файлы, zip

Нужно вытащить из архива отдельный файл и желательно в папку Assets. Пробовал создавать пустой файл(`File file=new File(path)`), но он не создавался, мб не правильно путь указывал, пробовал много способов, доступ к внешней памяти вроде как есть. Еще пробовал вариант с `OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("file:///android_asset/file.txt")`. Вообщем не получается, прошу помочь

Comment: Извините, не удержусь. Нет слова "вообщем", есть "в общем" и "вообще"

Comment: В assets ничего записать нельзя - это папка ресурсов, упакованная в дистрибутив приложения (APK) и доступна только для чтения.